# PHP - How to check for an empty array?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

Ok, this is easy, but I don't know why mine is not checking it!

I have an `if statement` that checks if an array is empty, if it's empty it should skip it, but all tries made not to skip it.

Here is the code:

```
$quizCounter = 0;
foreach ($quizzes as $key => $quiz) {

    if (!is_null($quiz['quiz_data'])) {

        echo "---->" . $key . "<BR>";

        unset($mark);
        $result = 0;
        $quizData = unserialize($quiz['quiz_data']);
        $quizTimestamp = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($quiz['time_stamp']));

        echo "Quiz: ";
        var_dump($quiz);
        echo "<BR>";

        echo "Quiz Data: ";
        var_dump($quizData);
        echo "<BR>";

        echo "Var Dump: ";
        var_dump($quizData['marks']);
        echo "<BR>";

        // Quiz marks
        if(!empty($quizData['marks'])) {
            foreach ($quizData['marks'] as $key => $marks) {
                $mark[$key] = $marks;
                echo "Mark: ";
                echo var_dump($marks) . "<BR>";
                $result += $marks;
            }
        }

        $markCounter = (count($mark) == 0) ? 1 : count($mark);
        $quizResult[$quizCounter] = $result / $markCounter;
        $quizCounter++;

    }

}
```

And here is the result that I need to skip:

```
---->34
Quiz: array(4) { ["quiz_data"]=> string(41) "a:2:{s:4:"ques";a:0:{}s:5:"marks";a:0:{}}" [0]=> string(41) "a:2:{s:4:"ques";a:0:{}s:5:"marks";a:0:{}}" ["time_stamp"]=> string(26) "0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000" [1]=> string(26) "0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000" } 
Quiz Data: array(2) { ["ques"]=> array(0) { } ["marks"]=> array(0) { } } 
Var Dump: array(0) { }
```

How may I skip this array?

Comment: if (count(array) > 0) ...

Comment: It didn't work also

Comment: Why it should be skipped?

Comment: To skip the current iteration of a loop, you use `continue;` (which you'd probably add in an `else` block I guess?). Not sure if that's what your question is though...

Comment: What exactly makes you think that you're going inside the `if` block in this case?

Comment: `if (34 == $key) { continue; }`

Comment: @Pyton, I guess that this empty array is causing other issues on my code.

Comment: @JonStirling, The problem here is that I can't even see that that `array` is empty, so the `else` doesn't work either.

Comment: @RobbieAverill, I can't do that because I don't know if another `array` will be empty. And on my tests, sometimes it was the `34`, sometimes the `37`, etc..

Comment: In that case, `if (empty($quizData['marks'])) { continue; }` as soon as you have `$quizData`. Don't you dare try and say it doesn't work, this is fundamentally simple stuff :)

Comment: @PatrickQ, before I was outputing something else to tell me, eventually I took it of and thought it was with error... You are right, It doesn't go inside the if statement... Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @RobbieAverill, thanks, I'll try that! It might work because it will not complete the iteration and add something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

This is a quote from the following page:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

The reason why your code considers `$quizData['marks']` as empty is because you have a variable equal to zero in `$quizData['marks']`. If you add another value that is not zero, your code should work.

Perhaps consider adding:

```
else if(isset($quizData['marks'])) {
    //proceed to print that person has a mark of zero
}
```